# Unable to trigger the Photo deletion window during UI testing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am attempting to create a UI Test in **XCode 10** that includes a step where the following window will appear:

[image]

(FYI - this is to support the creation of a video script, so we want to provide a full experience for the viewer)

Initially, I just recorded the steps to make sure I was properly capturing this request screen, and XCode dutifully logged out all of the steps.

Below is a lightly modified version from what XCode generates. For the record, using the unmodified version also fails.

```
func testDeletePhotos() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    continueAfterFailure = false
    app.launch()
    // Select two images from within app to delete
    let collectionViewsQuery = app.collectionViews
    collectionViewsQuery.children(matching: .cell)
        .element(boundBy: 1)
        .children(matching: .other)
        .element.children(matching: .other)
        .element(boundBy: 1)
        .tap()
    collectionViewsQuery.children(matching: .cell)
        .element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other)
        .element.children(matching: .other)
        .element(boundBy: 1)
        .tap()
    let navigationBar = app.navigationBars["MY_APP_NAME"]
    // Select the "Trash can" in nav bar to start delete process
    navigationBar.buttons["Delete"].tap()
    // Prompt appears properly and text is a precise match for string below
    // Below step fails with error seen below
    app.alerts["Allow “MY_APP_NAME” to delete 2 photos?"].buttons["Delete"].tap()

    navigationBar.buttons["Back"].tap()
}
```

However, when I attempt to re-run this script, it fails to locate the **Delete** button as seen in the above image.

> UI Test Activity:  Assertion Failure: MyVideoScript.swift:###: No
>   matches found for Find: Descendants matching type Alert from input {(
>       Application, pid: 17838, label: 'MY_APP_NAME' )}

Also, since someone may mention this - the quantity of photos is the same, as this will change the text that appears in the alert. I also attempted to use the `app.alerts.element(boundBy: 0)` in place of the name search and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The tap is probably performed before the alert finished appearing. You can tell the test to wait for it:

```
let deleteButton = app.alerts["Allow “MY_APP_NAME” to delete 2 photos?"].buttons["Delete"]
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")

expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: deleteButton, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: { error in
    // check for error, if none:
    deleteButton.tap()
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not present itself as an alert since it is driven by the OS and I cannot directly interface with it.